# XMLConfiguration writes properties twice

Tags: java, xml, configuration

I have encountered this problem: when I call org.apache.commons.configuration.XMLConfiguration.save(String fileName), it writes properties not changed twice.
E.g. I load all properties from this foo.xml:

```
<config>
    <foo>value</foo>
    <bar>value2</bar>
</config>
```

All loaded correctly. Then I change foo value by call XMLConfiguration.setProperty("foo", "new_value") and at once call XMLConfiguration.save(fileName) and I get following:

```
<config>
<foo>new_value</foo>
<bar>value2</bar>
<bar>value2</bar>
</config>
```

If close application, restart it and repeat these actions, number of bar's doubles again, but if change in one run all parameters, all is writed right.

I've tried write like this, but doesn't take result:

```
config.setProperty("bar", config.getString("bar"));
```

Please, help... I suspect, this is magic...

**UPD: Problem solved. Recipe is simple: don't call XMLConfiguration.load() because it called already in XMLConfiguration constructor.**

Comment: Post your code. Are you calling `XMLConfiguration.load` yourself? Don't. The constructor already calls `load` by itself. Calling it again will duplicate your fields. The ones you then set are probably 'fixing' the duplicates.

Comment: Thank you! I really called XMLConfiguration.load() and when comment this, problem was solved.